# Run docker command in Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I have an image that I need to start with special run arguments, i.e: `docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`.

How can I achieve this with Heroku?

---

Here's what I've tried -

In my `package.json` I have

`"start": "docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN..."`

In `Dockerfile` I have

`RUN npm start`

But when I start the dyno and run `heroku logs --tail` I get

`docker is not a command`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as containers cannot be run with root privileges on Heroku, see [Heroku Registry Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime).
It is safer/better to work locally with non-root user ensuring the same container can run on Heroku.